# Server Error: Error: Error serializing. Reason: `object` (“[object Object]”) cannot be serialized as JSON Next.js MongoDB

Tags: mongodb, serialization, next.js

I am working on an online shopping project and implying a review system for shopping products. I am using Next.js and MongoDB for my project. It works fine without any reviews submitted but when I submit my review and the error happened as below;
[image]

the error is from getServerSideProps in pages/product/[slug].js and the code is as below;

```
import axios from 'axios';
import Image from 'next/image';
import Link from 'next/link';
import { useRouter } from 'next/router'
import React, { useContext, useState, useEffect } from 'react'
import Layout from '../../components/Layout'
import Product from '../../models/Product';
import db from '../../utils/db';
import { Store } from '../../utils/Store';
import { toast } from 'react-toastify';
import Rating from '@material-ui/lab/Rating';
import { getSession } from 'next-auth/react';
import { useForm } from "react-hook-form";
import { getError } from '../../utils/error';

export default function ProductScreen (props) {

    const { product, user } = props;
    const {state, dispatch} = useContext(Store);
    const router = useRouter();
    const [ reviews, setReviews ] = useState([]);
    const [ rating, setRating ] = useState(0);
    const [ comment, setComment ] = useState('');
    const [ loading, setLoading ] = useState(false);

    const {
        handleSubmit,
        register,
        formState: { errors },
        setValue,
    } = useForm();

    const submitHandler = async () => {
        setLoading(true);
        try {
            await axios.post(`/api/products/${product._id}/reviews`, { rating, comment, user });
            setLoading(false);
            toast.success('Review submitted successfully');
            fetchReviews();
        } catch (err) {
            setLoading(false);
            return toast.error(getError(err));
        }
    }

    const fetchReviews = async () => {
        try {
            const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${product._id}/reviews`);
            setReviews(data);
        } catch (err) {
            return toast.error('fetchReview err');
        }
    }

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchReviews();
    }, []);

    if (!product) {
        return <Layout title="Product Not Found">Product Not Found</Layout>;
    }

    const addToCartHandler = async () => {
        const existItem = state.cart.cartItems.find((x) => x.slug === product.slug);
        const quantity = existItem ? existItem.quantity + 1 : 1;
        const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${product._id}`);

        if (data.countInStock < quantity) {
            return toast.error('Sorry. Product is out of stock');
        }

        dispatch ({ type: 'CART_ADD_ITEM', payload: { ...product, quantity }});
        router.push("/cart");
    };

    return (
        <Layout title={product.name}>
            <div className='py-2'>
                <Link href="/">back to products</Link>
            </div>
            <div className='grid md:grid-cols-4 md:gap-3'>
                <div className='md:col-span-2'>
                    <Image 
                        src={product.image}
                        alt={product.name}
                        width={640}
                        height={640}
                        layout='responsive'
                    />
                </div>
                <div>
                    <ul>
                        <li className='mt-4'>
                            <h1 className='text-lg'>{product.name}</h1>
                        </li>
                        <li className='mt-4'>Category: {product.category}</li>
                        <li className='mt-4'>Brand: {product.brand}</li>
                        <li className='flex mt-4'>
                            <Rating value={product.rating} readOnly />
                            <Link href='#reviews'>
                                <a>({product.numReviews} reviews)</a>
                            </Link>
                        </li>
                        <li className='mt-4'>Description: {product.description}</li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <div className='card p-5'>
                        <div className='mb-2 flex justify-between'>
                            <div>Price</div>
                            <div>${product.price}</div>
                        </div>
                        <div className='mb-2 flex justify-between'>
                            <div>Status</div>
                            <div>{product.countInStock > 0 ? 'In stock' : 'Unavailable'}</div>
                        </div>
                        <button className='primary-button w-full' onClick={addToCartHandler}>Add to cart</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div id='reviews' className='mt-4'>
                <h2 className='text-xl'>Customer Reviews</h2>
                {reviews.length === 0 && <div>No reviews</div>}
                
                {reviews.map((review) => (
                    <div key={review._id}>
                        {review.name}
                        {review.createdAt.substring(0, 10)}
                        <Rating value={review.rating} readOnly />
                        {review.comment}
                    </div>
                ))}

            </div>
            <div>
                {user ? (
                    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(submitHandler)}>
                        <h1>Leave your review</h1>
                        <div>
                            <Rating 
                                name='simple-controlled'
                                value={rating}
                                onChange={(e) => setRating(e.target.value)}
                            />
                            <label htmlFor='comment'>Comment</label>
                            <input 
                                type='text'
                                {...register('comment', { required: 'Please enter comment',})}
                                id='comment'
                                value={comment}
                                onChange={(e) => setComment(e.target.value)}
                            />
                            {errors.comment && (
                                <div className='text-red-500'>{errors.comment.message}</div>
                            )}
                            <button className='primary-button'>
                                {loading? 'Loading' : 'Submit'}
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </form>
                ) : (
                    <div>
                        Please <Link href={`/login?redirect=/product/${product.slug}`}>Login</Link> to write a review.
                    </div>
                )}
            </div>
        </Layout>
    )
}

export async function getServerSideProps(context) {
    const { params, req } = context;
    const { slug } = params;
    const session = await getSession({ req });

    await db.connect();
    const product = await Product.findOne({ slug }).lean();
    await db.disconnect();

    return (
        {
            props: {
                product: product ? db.convertDocToObj(product) : null,
                user: session ? session : null,
            },
        }
    );
}
```

as my understanding, the getServerSideProps function at the bottom should convert the props into object with below code;
`product: product ? db.convertDocToObj(product) : null,`
am I using it correctly?

my product schema with review is as below;

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const reviewSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    user: { type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    rating: { type: Number, default: 5 },
    comment: { type: String, required: true },
},
{
    timestamps: true,
});

const productSchema = new mongoose.Schema(
    {
        name: { type: String, required: true },
        slug: { type: String, required: true, unique: true },
        category: { type: String, required: true },
        image: { type: String, required: true },
        price: { type: Number, required: true },
        brand: { type: String, required: true },
        rating: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
        numReviews: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
        countInStock: { type: Number, required: true, default: 0 },
        description: { type: String, required: true },
        reviews: [reviewSchema],
    }, {
        timestamps: true,
    }
);

const Product = mongoose.models.Product || mongoose.model('Product', productSchema);
export default Product;
```

the MongoDB Compass for Product is as below;
[image]

So, how can I fix my problew?

Thanks

Stan

Answer (score 1):

Set `props` like this:

```
props:{
  product: product ? JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(product)) : null,
  user: session ? session : null,
}
```

See discussion here: https://github.com/vercel/next.js/issues/11993

Answer (score 0):

latest `Axios` version(v1.2.0) changed header field, it is know issue
Not working old code, so you can avoid this error by adding header information.
https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/5298

Your three `axios` API call needs to add header with correct content type.
(I suppose all of json type in your code)

before

```
await axios.post(`/api/products/${product._id}/reviews`, { rating, comment, user });
const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${product._id}`);
const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${product._id}/reviews`);
```

after

```
await axios.post(`/api/products/${product._id}/reviews`, { rating, comment, user }, {
    headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    }
});

const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${product._id}`,
{
    headers: {
         'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json'
    }
});

const { data } = await axios.get(`/api/products/${product._id}/reviews`,
{
    headers: {
         'Accept-Encoding': 'application/json'
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Bench, thank you for your answer. I have tried to add the headers to all my axios as you mentioned. but the error still here. Do you have any hints to solve the error?

Comment: Hi @StanleyLeung,  My answer only cover axios call, you need to check this works by `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` after axios get call. I don't know the other part(mongoose)

Comment: Bench, noted with that and thanks